# C++ class variable not changes after assignment

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I have two classes and one is a private variable in the other.
The private member has a base class that have a variable as a private member.
The code is like below:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
    public:
  Base(): _p(5) {
      
  }
    
  void setP(int p) {
      _p = p;
  }
  
  int p() const {
      return _p;
  }
private:
  int _p = 0;
};

class Test:  public Base {
    public:
  Test(): Base() {
  }
  
  Test operator=(const Test & self) {
      Test cloned;
      cloned.setP(self.p());
      return cloned;
  }
};

class Test2:  public Base {
    public:
  Test2() {
  }
  
  Test2 operator=(const Test2 & self) {
      Test2 cloned;
      cloned.setTest(self.test());
      return cloned;
  }
  
  Test test() const { return _test; }
  void setTest(const Test & test) { _test = test; }
  
  private:
  Test _test;
};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    test.setP(500);
    
    Test2 newTest;
    newTest.setTest(test);
  
    Test2 newTest2 = newTest;
    std::cout << "p is " << newTest.test().p() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "p2 is " << newTest2.test().p() << std::endl;
}
```

I checked the code insights and see some operator='s and some copy constructors, but I can't figure it out how can this happens..

When I run this program I expect output to be like this:

```
p is 500                                                                                                          
p is 500
```

But I get this:

```
p is 5                                                                                                               
p is 5
```

Comment: `Test`'s assignment operator doesn't actually assign - that is, it leaves the left-hand side of the assignment unchanged. Thus, `_test = test;` in `Test2::setTest` is a no-op.

Comment: An assignment operator is expected to modify `*this`, not return a new object.

Comment: yes @IgorTandetnik, thanks to mention that...

Comment: @molbdnilo you are right, thank you. A silly mistake mistake happened by me ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `operator=`. You create a temporary `Test` and modify that, but you do not modify `this` object. The correct implementation is:

```
 Test& operator=(const Test& rhs) {
     setP(rhs.p());
     return *this;
 }
```

Please also note that `operator=` returns a reference `Test&`, not a `Test`.